# Display Alphabetical order a list of name and surname

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I need to display in alphabetical order a list of name and surname (order by surname).
The problem is I can't do a ORDER BY in SQL query because I retrieve my users ID in one table and retrieve the informations in another table.

My PHP code:

```
$sql = "select id FROM $table_name";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ($result as $record) {
    $id = $record->id;

    $sql2 = "select field_name, field_val FROM $table_name2 where sub_id = $id";
    $result2 = $wpdb->get_results($sql2);
    foreach ($result2 as $record2) {
        if($record2->field_name == "Nom :") {
            $surname = ucfirst(stripslashes($record2->field_val));
        }
        if($record2->field_name == "Prénom :") {
            $name = ucfirst(stripslashes($record2->field_val));
        }
    }

    echo $name . " " . $surname . "<br/>";
}
```

Here the architecture of the second table:

```
f_id    sub_id      field_name      field_val
127     19          Prénom :        Philippe
128     19          Nom :           Nailloux
129     20          Prénom :        John
130     20          Nom :           Drumond
```

Have you an idea how I can display my list ordered by surname alphabetically?

Thanks.

Comment: This is where learning about [SQL JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) would be very useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the trick by using this SQL query :

```
SELECT t1.id        AS user_id, 
       t2.field_val AS surname, 
       t3.field_val AS name 
FROM   $table_name t1 
       JOIN $table_name2 AS t2 
         ON ( t2.sub_id = t1.id 
              AND t2.field_name = 'Nom :' ) 
       JOIN $table_name2 AS t3 
         ON ( t3.sub_id = t1.id 
              AND t3.field_name = 'Prénom :' ) 
ORDER  BY t2.field_val
```

The query will return all the infos needed (user_id, surname and name) ordered by surname.

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries!

In your example, let's say you have 100 users.
In first query you get your users ids, then **for each user** you query database for one's data. **That's 101 queries for a simple operation!** What if you have 10 visits per seconds? That's more than 1000 queries.

There are many strategies (subquery, join, two queries with `in ()` in second one) but in this case consider that:

```
SELECT 
  field_name, field_val
FROM
  $table_name2
WHERE
  sub_id IN(
    SELECT 
      id 
    FROM 
      $table_name
  ) as sq1
ORDER BY field_val ASC;
```

Also consider using `PHP PDO`, or at least proper escaping of data you put in queries.